# Define and calculate Apples definition of the unit point

Tags: ios

Apple writes in the [user interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW20) that a tappable element should be at least 44 x 44 points. They provide an example of the calculator app for reference. When I measured the tappable buttons I got the height of 10 mm/38 px. Using tools I found online I converted this to approximately 29 postscript points.

My question is what does Apple mean by 44 points? How do I convert this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Apple's use of 'point' is not the same as a typographical point. It's an abstract unit that doesn't have a fixed correlation to pixels, nor to any physical measurement (e.g., millimeters).

The first part of that is easy to see; a point width on a retina iPhone covers two pixels, twice as many as on a non-retina iPhone.

The iPad Mini makes the second part of that first statement pretty clear. From an iOS developer's point of view, 44 points is the same measurement on an iPad 2 as it is on the mini. But to a user, those represent very different physical (millimeter) sizes.

There's a bit more written under Points vs Pixels in their [drawing guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html).

It does seem a bit strange for the HIG to prescribe sizes that don't correspond to, well, humans. In practice, for a UX designer, your approximations are probably fine.

Answer (score -1):

A point is 1/72 of an inch, so 44 points is 0.6 inch or 1.5 cm. I don't think Apple can change this definition all by themselves.

Comment: But if I use that then I get a completely different size than the reference. 44 * 0.3527 = 15.5188 mm which is 5 mm bigger then the buttons in the calculator app

Comment: Maybe they made a mistake, or they used a screen with a different pixel size. Like I said, they can't just change the definition of what a point is.

Comment: I thought of that and then I measured the buttons in the actual app on my Iphone and the height of the buttons there is only 6.5 mm which is only 18.42 points

Comment: Actually Apple CAN and DOES change the definition of a point. It's just that it is a logical UIKit point now.